# Android Dependencies Error: Libraries must match the same version

Tags: java, android, dependencies, libraries

As you can see, i think all the support libraries have same version then why this error?

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
```

}

Comment: May be this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49837525/8942811 help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be 2 reasons:

1) When you hover over the error it will probably  tell you which library has the wrong version, and maybe it's not even  present in your dependencies, but probably one of your libraries is internally using it, so you need to specify them separately with the same version.

2) Or it may be due to the fact that one of the libraries (it's probably firebase) is compiled against a different version of the support library  and that's causing the conflict. So you need your support libraries to match the support library that firebase is compiled against. For example look at how Glide explains it [here](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/download-setup.html):

> Support Library Version - Glide uses support library version 27.
>
> If you need or would prefer to use a different version of the support library you should exclude "com.android.support" from your Glide dependency in your build.gradle file.

So to check, if you delete the firebase dependency it will probably build. If that's the case, then you need to check against which version your version of firebase is compiled and use that.